# SQL join with dates

Tags: sql, join

I have table A with columns:

```
customer_id, month, amount
```

Month is like `2015/12/01` meaning it's amount paid in December 2015.

Then there is table B with columns:

```
customer_id, plan_id, start_date, end_date
```

This is information on when a particular customer started and ended using a particular plan. The current plan will have `end_date NULL`. One customer could have used many different plans in the past.

I need to add `plan_id` column to table A by joining these 2 tables but I have no idea how to deal with the dates.

Note that for each customer one month should correspond to one plan only. So even if the `start_date` for a plan is 2015/11/02, it should only be applied for the next month (2015/12/01).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a basically a join, but with inequalities:

```
select a.*, b.*
from a left join
     b
     on a.customer_id = b.customer_id and
        a.month >= b.start_date and
        (a.month <= b.end_date or b.end_date is null);
```

Comment: It works, only ">" needs to be replaced with "<" in the last line: a.month <= b.end_date